# Express isn't sending JSON, but it's sending other strings fine

Tags: node.js, express

Here's the code:

```
res.status(400).send('{"test":1}');
```

This returns an empty response. This returns "test":

```
res.status(400).send('test');
```

Here's the only extension I'm using:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb', type: 'application/*' }));
```

How do I make Express send JSON? I'm using Express 4.16.3 (latest version).

Edit, here's the whole file. I'm using Express as a proxy:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const qs = require('qs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const API_URL = 'https://api.example.com/';

const app = express();
app.set('json spaces', 2);
Error.stackTraceLimit = 100;
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb', type: 'application/*' }));

app.options(/\/api\/(.+)/, async (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': false,
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '86400',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept',
  });
  res.end();
});

app.all(/\/api\/(.+)/, async (req, res) => {
  let url = API_URL + req.params[0];
  if (Object.keys(req.query).length) {
    url += `?${qs.stringify(req.query)}`;
  }

  const opts = {
    method: req.method,
    headers: {
      'content-type': req.headers['content-type'] || 'application/json',
    },
  };
  if (req.headers.authorization) {
    opts.headers.authorization = req.headers.authorization;
  }
  if (req.method.toUpperCase() !== 'GET') {
    opts.body = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  }

  res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
  try {
    const result = await fetch(url, opts);
    const data = await result.text();
    res.status(result.status).send({"test":1});
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message || err);
  }
});

app.listen(9002, () => console.log('Server started.'));
```

Comment: res.status(400).send({"test":1});

Comment: @GiannisMp it's the same thing, "This request has no response data available" in Chrome's network tab.

Comment: Why the downvote and close, no one answered it yet.

Comment: The close vote is because the code you've provided works fine and so there's not enough information in your question in order for someone to be able to answer it.

Comment: Are you issuing a `POST` or a `GET`? Does it make a difference if you try both?

Comment: There's also `res.json(obj)` where you can pass a Javascript object and it will convert it to JSON for you.

Comment: It was a CORS issue, I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

It was a CORS issue. It worked after adding:

```
  res.header('access-control-allow-origin', '*');
  res.header('access-control-allow-headers', 'origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept');
```

I don't know why it worked with a non-JSON string, but it was blocked if the response was JSON.

Answer (score 0):

To let express pass json object you can try to use this:

```
app.use(express.json());
```